# Side-effects only when using Pipeable Operators?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm rewriting some of my code to use Pipeable Operators in place of "patch" operators and I'm a little confused about when to use `pipe()` and how do I subscribe to a piped `Observable` to "activate" it if I only want side-effects?

For example, I have this code:

```
this.messages$ = this.messageService.getMessages(messageType)
    .do((messages: Message[]) => {
        console.log('The first message is ' + deviceMessages[0].text);
    });
```

I get confused here because I figure I want to do `this.messageService.getMessages(messageType).pipe(...)` so I get an `Observable` returned and assigned to `this.messages$` but then that won't execute because I haven't `subscribe()`'d. But if I do `.pipe(...).subscribe()` then it'll return a `Subscription` object, which isn't what I want.

What should I be doing here?

Comment: `.pipe(tap(...))` is equivalent to `.do(...)`. Whether you use pipeable operators or not doesn't change anything to how observables work, and to when you should subscribe. You subscribe to trigger the emission of the events (here, probably by sending an HTTP request), just as before.

Comment: @JBNizet So are you saying I should keep the `do()` and leave it the way it is?

Comment: No, he/she is saying to switch it to `.pipe(tap(...))` instead of `.do(...)` and nothing else has to change.

Comment: Exactly as Sean Bright said.

Comment: @SeanBright @JBNizet Hmm but when I tried `.pipe(tap(...))` I wasn't getting any execution of the code inside of `tap()` -- I figured this was because I didn't `.subscribe()` -- so you're saying that `.pipe()` should activate the Observable sequence too?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, but neither does `do()`. Is your current code with `do()` doing something without subscribing? If so, that is a bug.

Comment: @SeanBright if that's true then I think I figured it out, in my Angular HTML tempalte it must be the `async` pipes doing the subscribing! Right?

Comment: That is what the `async` pipe does, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do it simply like this:

```
this.messages$ = this.messageService.getMessages(messageType).pipe(
  tap((messages: Message[]) => {
    console.log('The first message is ' + deviceMessages[0].text);
  })
);
this.messages$.subscribe();
```

the tap operator is the equivalent of `.do()` in rxjs 5 and above.